# Controlling Ethernet through Python for local communication between 2 microcontrollers

Tags: python, microcontroller, ethernet, serial-communication, jetson-xavier

I want to interface an NVIDIA Jetson AGX Xavier with a Teensy 4.1 via Ethernet (and Ethernet adapter for Teensy), the control units don't have to be connected to the internet. I would like to know what steps I need to take for making this communication possible; is there any other hardware i need besides the two control units and the Ethernet adapter? How do I set up Ethernet communication through Python? The Jetson will process camera views and send signals based on the view, the Teensy subsequently controls electric motors. The control units need full-duplex communication. Thanks in advance!

I tried looking it up, but information is quite limited on this subject, maybe because these types of applications are more usually done with C++?

Comment: this is probably not a stackoverflow question but anyway are you using ethernet as in wired (gigabit?  10/100?) or wifi?  for wired you simply force the ip addresses and addresses on the same subnet and then they will just talk, if you want dns or anything like  that  then you need to do more work,  you can have one side serve dchp, dns, etc for the other.

Comment: Yes wired Ethernet, it allows for 10/100 Mbps speed. So you can assign a static IP yourself? And you just put the IP a in the code or EEPROM settings? Thanks for the help!